# Create Shortcut on Desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a client who is wanting to allow visitors to add a shortcut for his website to their desktop. So you click a link and it creates the shortcut. I've never heard of anything like this and can't really find anything through searching. Is this possible? How would I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you could write files at will on your users machine using javascript, then it would be a tremendous security issue. the short answer is It cant be done.

Comment: Yeah I figured that was the case, but I thought better to ask just to be sure. Thanks!

Comment: the best thing you can do is create a downloadable shortcut and ask your users to save it on the desktop.

Answer (score 3):

They can just drag it from the url bar to their desktop and it creates a link... At least on Macs!

Comment: 'cept he wants it to happen automagically by clicking a link.

Comment: Okay, then take the file you dragged to the desktop, upload it to mediafire, right click on the download link and click copy, then when they click on that link, this shortcut will be on their desktop. Not seeing a need for this but hey.